# Puppet: Package Provider - what is the "query" method for?

Tags: package, puppet

I am building a custom package provider, and I am not sure what the query method is supposed to return.

Eg of a package provider:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/package/dpkg.rb

Found example of package provider, but no documentation of what each method is supposed to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query method is called by the `Puppet::Provider::Package` base type. The `properties` method populates the `property_hash` using the `query` method:

```
  # Look up the current status.
  def properties
    if @property_hash.empty?
      @property_hash = query || {:ensure => :absent}
      @property_hash[:ensure] = :absent if @property_hash.empty?
    end
    @property_hash.dup
  end
```

In the rubydoc of `Puppet::Provider` it says the following about the `property_hash`:

> **Property hash** - the important instance variable `@property_hash` contains all current state values for properties (it is lazily built).
>   It is important that these values are managed appropriately in the
>   methods {instances}, {prefetch}, and in methods that alters the
>   current state (those that change the lifecycle (creates, destroys), or
>   alters some value reflected backed by a property).

Thus, query should return a hash that reflects the current state of the package expressed in Puppet's [package properties](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package).

This is not documented AFAIK. I figured it out by reverse engineering.

Hope this helps. Good luck!